# Query in MSSQL that returns .mdf and .ldf filename/location for specific database?

Tags: sql-server

Can I use a query in MSSQL to get the .mdf and .ldf filename/location for a specific database?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SELECT * FROM [sys.database_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397(SQL.90).aspx) (SQL 2005+)

SELECT * FROM dbo.sysfiles (SQL 2000)

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
exec sp_helpfile
```

Will return a query containing information about the files of the current database.

This will work on any SQL server version.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.master_files
```

...will give you a basic view of where your database lives. It might not cope too well with filegroups, etc.

Comment: This query shows the location of all attached databases, which was exactly what I needed. Thanks!